# How to order by column with null values last in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know how to return an ordered list of strings with null values last?  I have something like this:

```
using(var context = new DomainEntities())
{
    var result = context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName).ThenBy(u => u.FirstName);
}
```

My problem though is that this query returns null values before non-null values.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I would do:

```
using(var context = new DomainEntities())
{
    var result = context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName == null)
                              .ThenBy(u => u.LastName)
                              .ThenBy(u => u.FirstName == null)
                              .ThenBy(u => u.FirstName);
}
```

...which should produce reasonable SQL.

EDIT: explanation (taken from Craig's comment):

Because `false` sorts before `true`.

Comment: So this does work but I'm confused as to why it works.  Why would specifying LastName == null return non-null values first?

Comment: Because `false` sorts before `true`.

Comment: Is that first semi-colon a type-o (after the check for u.FirstName == null) ?

Comment: to make this answer complete, I think it is better to add your comment to the answer itself.
"Because false sorts before true."

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there's some switch somewhere that you can flip. Otherwise, the straight forward approach would probably be something along the lines of

```
    using (var context = new DomainEntities())
    {
        var FirstPart = context.Users.Where(u => u.LastName != null);
        var SecondPart = context.Users.Where(u => u.LastName == null);
        var Result = FirstPart.Union(SecondPart);
    }
```

Comment: That will produce fairly ugly SQL, I suspect.

Comment: Define ugly :) Actually, it won't be as bad as you might think - for SQL Server 2008 at least, EF turns something like this into a single db query statement.

Comment: It will be one statement, yes, just overly complicated.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName ?? x.LastName);
```

Comment: EF Core 6 gives me `....could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

Answer (score 0):

With mysql you can use dash symbol before the column name inside OrderBy, like so:

```
dbContext.Stats.OrderByDescending(i => -i.Bound).ToList();
```