# Is null Property in LInq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
select * from Toys Order by isnull(ModifiedOn ,CreatedOn) DESC
```

I want  DESC  Result at the Basis of ModifiedOn if it is null so i want this  go to at the Basis of  CreatedOn

so far I did is

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).ThenByDescending(x => x.ModifiedOn)
```

But Could not Achive ?

AnyOne have Idea  how can i achive this ?

Comment: Try `.OrderByDescending(x => x.ModifiedOn ??  x.CreatedOn)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order by column with null values last in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814742/how-to-order-by-column-with-null-values-last-in-entity-framework)